# Circe failed to decode JSON containing list

Tags: scala, circe

I have a situation

```
  abstract class Abc
  final case class JsonRecord(payload: Json) extends Abc
  final case class Record(subj: String, record: JsonRecord)
```

I have API endpoint that takes in

```
final case class Bulk(records: Seq[Record])
```

Circe is not able to decode this when I send a json like

```
    {"records": [
      {
"subj": "dsf",
        "record": {
          "payload": {
            "value": "xxx",
            "age": 3
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    }
```

It complains like this

```
DecodingFailure(Attempt to decode value on failed cursor, List(DownField(payload)))
```

Comment: It works for me. Which **circe** and **scala** versions are you using? - Also, is `Json` here referring to `io.circe.Json`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yesit refers to io.circe.Json

Comment: scala version 13 and circe 0.13.0

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Can you show me how is it working for you ?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I have edited the question to represent my actual class structure

Comment: [It keeps working](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/zqXz0aHGQsWxGsyEPTzmXg/2) let me know if you have any question.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It might be a issue with Tapir. Even a simple endpoint like this not working

`val endPoint: Route[List[String], String] =
      endpoint.post
        .in(Versions.current / Paths.api / "_bulk1")
        .in(jsonBody[List[String]])
        .out(jsonBody[String])
        .errorOut(Errors.Common)`